# Angular8: Prototype Inheritence with Date Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I was trying to find a way to add some methods to Date prototype in Angular(Typescript) and found the below solution via GitHub which works well.

date.extensions.ts

```
export {}

// DATE EXTENSIONS
// ================

declare global {
   interface Date {
      addDays(days: number, useThis?: boolean): Date;
      isToday(): boolean;
      clone(): Date;
      isAnotherMonth(date: Date): boolean;
      isWeekend(): boolean;
      isSameDate(date: Date): boolean;
   }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = (days: number): Date => {
   if (!days) return this;
   console.log(this);
   let date = this;
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

   return date;
};

Date.prototype.isToday = (): boolean => {
   let today = new Date();
   return this.isSameDate(today);
};

Date.prototype.clone = (): Date => {
   return new Date(+this);
};

Date.prototype.isAnotherMonth = (date: Date): boolean => {
   return date && this.getMonth() !== date.getMonth();
};

Date.prototype.isWeekend = (): boolean => {
   return this.getDay() === 0 || this.getDay() === 6;
};

Date.prototype.isSameDate = (date: Date): boolean => {
   return date && this.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() && this.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && this.getDate() === date.getDate();
};
```

Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7726#issuecomment-234469961

Question: Can someone tell me why `export {}` is written at the start of the TS file and why is it so necessary to add here?

Answer (score 0):

without export any thing from the `date.extensions.ts` the file will not consider a module 
and you will have three errors

```
error TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.

error TS2306: File 'date.extensions.ts' is not a module.

and an error about the Date type
```

simply `export {}` use to make the filw as module becuase has export something